# How to get rid of Emma plugin in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I inherited a Jenkins server. Someone had played with the Emma plugin, which I do not need.

When I uncheck the "Enabled" checkbox for the Emma plugin on the Plugin Manager page, my projects vanish. Well, fortunately, not completely: they are still on disk and can be recovered by enabling that plugin again.

I checked the xml files for those projects, but I cannot find any reference to Emma there. On the project page, a place-holder for a non-available image is shown which provides a link to lastbuild/emma (which is not available).

What can I do here?

Comment: Are you restarting Jenkins after disabling the plugins? If the Emma image is appearing on the pages of older builds, then it would suggest that Jenkins wasn't restarted, and that there's Emma-related info in `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/<job>/builds/<build>/build.xml`.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr Thanks for the hints. After disabling the Emma plugin, Jenkins is restarted. I removed old builds from the folder and tried again: the job is no more shown.

Comment: You shouldn't need to remove the build XML files; if a plugin doesn't load (e.g. because it was uninstalled) Jenkins just ignores any data from that plugin when loading job configs and build data. But anyway, if you say the configured job itself is gone after a restart, that's very odd. Do you see any related errors in the Jenkins log files (for most installs `/var/log/jenkins`), or in Manage Jenkins > System Logs > All Jenkins logs?

Comment: Error message: Failed Loading job xyz
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hudson/plugins/emma/EmmaPublisher
 at hudson.plugins.mstest.MSTestPublisher.getProjectActions(MSTestPublisher.java:93)

Comment: You have the [MSTest Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/MSTest+Plugin) installed, which lists the Emma plugin as a required dependency.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. After setting the MSTest plugin disabled, all jobs were still present. Afterwards, I could set the Emma plugin disabled, and the jobs were still here.